# Unity2D - Player relative animation positioning

Tags: animation, position, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer and I've come across a really annoying problem where if I move my player character GameObject to another location on the scene, my player becomes stuck and the game spazzes out, jumping from the players original location and the position I moved it to.

My player character is made up of many parts, each a separate GameObject. I know the problem is definitely in my animation, because if I disable the animator component, the problem goes away, just I don't have my animations anymore. I believe the problem may be in the player character's Idle Animation and it's position property. There is no script attached where his starting location is hard coded.

How can I make the child Gameobjects move relative to the parent Player GameObject? I cannot move the player in the scene from its original location without the game glitching up.

Here are some screenshots

[Player and it's parts in Hierarchy]http://i67.tinypic.com/bdlc1j.png

[Idle Animation]http://i64.tinypic.com/2gtp99x.png

[Player's original Location, he works if starting here] http://i66.tinypic.com/261jb6c.png

[Player is Moved, game bugs out] http://i67.tinypic.com/292a2c3.png

Comment: This is strange. Somehow the animation is trying to animate the `Beetle: Position` try deleting `Chest: position`, `Torso: position` and `Shell: position` from the animation and see what happens.

Comment: After playing around with the animation enough, I think the problem may lie somewhere within my animator, and the player gameObjects parameters. I've noticed my 'vSpeed' float parameter `rigidbody2D.velocity.y` is constantly dropping and therefore keeps my player character stuck in the mid-air jump animation, but I cannot move as it's not 'grounded'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable "Apply Root Motion" flag in the Animator component.
The problem should be related to the fact that the animation changes the position values

Comment: Yup. that's unchecked. My player character can actually move nicely and smoothly, with the body parts staying together and everything as the main parent gameObject doesn't move in the animation, just the children. Only it glitches up when I move the parent gameObject to another position on the scene.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that  you have animated the different parts by moving then around in the editor and recording that. This meas that the animation is keeping track of the original position at which you did the animation. Try deleting those parts from the animation.

Comment: Yes I have moved the different parts around, but that shouldn't matter because they're all child gameObjects moving within a parent gameObject that doesn't move with animation on that parent itself, but by code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the spazzy-jittering problem that occurs when I move the player character to another position on the scene, but I did find a way around it. The problem definitely lied within the Animator component and the gameObject's Rigidbody2d.

Instead of moving the player to another position, I instead made a 'Spawn Point' which the player starts from when first playing the scene, and that was able to be moved freely around. Pretty much:

`void start(){
transform.position = spawnPoint.transform.position;
}`